# Date picker is reseted on 1 Jan 1970

Tags: android, date, kotlin, android-datepicker

I have field `date` in my firebase realtime database.

And now for example if i enter in fragment and don't change the date, date changing on: `1 Jan 1970` even if it has been installed before.

This is code of my fragment:

```
class TargetEditFragment : BaseFragment(), View.OnClickListener, TargetEditContract {

    private val presenter = TargetEditPresenter(contract = this)
    private val safeArgs: TargetEditFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private val targetGuid: String
        get() = safeArgs.guid
    private var parsedDate: LocalDate? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        presenter.setInitialData(targetGuid)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_target_add, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        presenter.fetchTarget()
        setupViews()
    }

    override fun updateViewsContent(
        name: String?,
        date: String?
    ) {
        nameEditText?.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(name)
        dateView?.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(date)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        presenter.onViewClick(v?.id ?: return, targetGuid)
    }

    override fun editTarget(targetGuid: String) {
        val name = nameEditText?.text.toString().trim()
        val date = parsedDate?.atStartOfDay()?.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)?.toEpochMilli() ?: 0L
        if (targetGuid.isEmpty()) presenter.addTarget(name, date)
        else presenter.updateTarget(name, date)
    }

    override fun deleteTarget() {
        presenter.deleteTarget()
    }

    override fun closeView() {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.show_list)
    }

    override fun showWarningDialog() {
        activity?.showWarningDialog(description = getString(R.string.warning_description))
    }

    private fun setupViews() {
        showDatePickerDialog()
        addActionView?.setOnClickListener(this)
        deleteActionView?.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
        val date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        val currentYear = date.year
        val currentMonth = date.monthValue
        val currentDay = date.dayOfMonth

        val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)

        pickDate.setOnClickListener {
            val datePickDialog = DatePickerDialog(
                activity,
                R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    val selectedDate = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth)
                    val dateString = selectedDate.format(dateFormatter)
                    dateView.text = dateString
                    parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter)
                },
                currentYear,
                currentMonth - 1,
                currentDay
            )
            datePickDialog.show()

            datePickDialog.setOnCancelListener { dialog -> dialog.dismiss() }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
I see that is because i put elvis `0L`. But how it fix correct?

If i don't call `showDatePickerDialog` my `parsedDate` always will be `null`.
But in fun `editTarget` i need get saved date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that is because i put elvis 0L. But how it fix correct?
>
> If i don't call showDatePickerDialog my parsedDate always will be null. But in fun editTarget i need get saved date.

Exactly. If you want the fallback to be something that isn't Jan 1, 1970, then you need to set `parsedDate` to whatever it is supposed to be. You say it is in a Firebase realtime database, but I don't see anywhere that you are referencing that database to get the value so that it can be set appropriately.

My suggestion would be to have the presenter make a call to your data layer to listen for updates to the relevant realtime database value and have a callback in your Fragment that updates `parsedDate` whenever the database value is updated.

Comment: Here is my presenter: https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/aadd36552d09c3e8baeb41b94652abc0
Is it possible to pull a date from these methods?